# ArcGIS Server Object Extension for Analyzing Linearly Referenced Data

Tags: arcgis-server, rest, server-object-extension, linear-referencing

I have just begun learning about the ArcGIS Server Object Extension (SOE) capabilities, specificially with ArcGIS 10.

Is there an example available of an SOE that can return information about linearly referenced data?  For example, if I am using an Event Table to manage data about speed limits along a highway, I am trying to find an SOE that can return the exact speed limit, given a measurement along the highway.

In addition, I am trying to learn more about Custom SOEs being accessed through the ArcGIS Server REST service handler.  Does anyone know of any examples of something similar?

Thanks,
Seth

Comment: Given a Route ID and a distance (measure), the speed limit from an Event table could be returned from a non-GIS web service.

Perhaps you will want to find the route and measure based on a point? If so, that would be an appropriate thing for an SOE.

Answer (score 3):

The [ElevationsSOE blog post](http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/apl/archive/2010/10/07/Elevation-Server-Object-Extension.aspx) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

you can see http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/arcgisserver/archive/2011/08/19/A-server-object-extension-for-performing-dynamic-segmentation.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+ArcgisServerDevelopmentBlog+%28ArcGIS+Server+Development+Blog%29

you can see also my soe
http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=e3bfa7c991e34aa8872c937ca9169507